# Light movement doesn't have effect

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, light

I am writing an interactive program, where the user can change the material, the light and the object that is displayed. The part where I write all the HTML tables and javascript events to handle user interactions, I think that works fine, so I am posting here just the relevant parts, I'll add a link to the whole file.

Here I create the scene, the object, the light and the rendering function:

```
var scene= new THREE.Scene();
var camera= new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000);
var renderer= new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera.position.z=5;


var geometry= new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,15,15);
var material= new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xffffff, ambient:0xffffff, emissive:0xffffff});
var object= new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
material.name= "lambert";
object.name= "sphere";
scene.add(object);

var light= new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set(0,0,20);
light.name= "point";
scene.add(light);


var render= function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
render();
```

Then every time that the user, through a button, changes a parameter, I use these functions to change the material and light characteristics:

```
function changeLightParameters() {
    var lightParameters= getLightParameters();
    if(lightParameters== null) {
        alert("Invalid values");
        return;
    }
    if(light.name!= lightParameters.type) {
        scene.remove(light);
        if(lightParameters.type== "spot") {
            light= new THREE.SpotLight(lightParameters.color);
        }
        else if(lightParameters.type== "point") {
            light= new THREE.PointLight(lightParameters.color);
        }
        else if(lightParameters.type== "ambient") {
            light= new THREE.AmbientLight(lightParameters.color);
        }
        else if(lightParameters.type== "area") {
            light= new THREE.AreaLight(lightParameters.color);
        }
        else if(lightParameters.type== "directional") {
            light= new THREE.DirectionalLight(lightParameters.color);
        }
        light.position.set(lightParameters.position.x, lightParameters.position.y, lightParameters.position.z);
        light.name= lightParameters.name;
        scene.add(light);
    }
    else {
        light.position= lightParameters.position;
        light.color= new THREE.Color(lightParameters.color);
    }
}


function changeMaterialParameters() {
    var materialParameters= getMaterialParameters();
    if(materialParameters== null) {
        alert("Invalid values");
        return;
    }
    if(materialParameters.type!= material.name) {
        scene.remove(object);
        if(materialParameters.type== "lambert") {
            material= new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color:materialParameters.diffuse, 
                ambient:materialParameters.ambient,
                emissive:materialParameters.emissive });
        }
        else if(materialParameters.type== "normal") {
            material= new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        }
        else if(materialParameters.type== "phong") {
            material= new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                color:materialParameters.diffuse,
                ambient:materialParameters.ambient,
                emissive:materialParameters.emissive,
                specular:materialParameters.specular,
                shininess:materialParameters.shininess });
        }
        material.name= materialParameters.type;
        object= new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
        scene.add(object);
    }
    else {
        material.color= new THREE.Color(materialParameters.diffuse);
        material.ambient= new THREE.Color(materialParameters.ambient);
        material.emissive= new THREE.Color(materialParameters.emissive);
        material.specular= new THREE.Color(materialParameters.specular);
        material.shininess= new THREE.Color(materialParameters.shininess);
        material.needsUpdate= true;
    }
}
```

In these functions I use `getMaterialParameters()` and `getLightParameters()` to get all the parameters passed in two tables containing some text fields to handle the values. I already tested these functions and they work, so it's not necessary to see the code. These functions return an object with this structure:

```
Light : color (number)
        position (THREE.Vector3)
        type (string, possibile values "ambient", "point", "spot", "point", "directional")

Material: diffuse (number)
          ambient (number)
          emissive (number)
          specular (number)
          shininess (number)
          type (string, possible values "phong", "normal", "lambert")
```

Once got the material properties if the material type has changed, I create a new material from scratch, if instead just it's properties are changed I update it. Same for the light.

The problem is that the object seems irresponsive to light changes: if I change the light position/color nothing happens. I may also set the light's z to be -1000 that nothing changes. The Phong model doesn't seem correct to me, the object doesn't shine like it should. Example:

[image]

The parameters are:  Phong material, shininess 100, diffuse light 0x00abb1, emissive light 0x006063, specular light 0xa9fcff, shininess light 100. White point light in position (20,20,200). If I displace the light to (0,0,0) the sphere looks the same. It doesn't seem realistic like it should, I think I'm doing something wrong.

Please tell me if I need to add more details, the full code is here:  http://pastebin.com/3uwgwvfE

**Update**

I discover that the problem consists in the fact that I am not able to add a new light when the scene is already initialized. I've made a new program that is an example of how reproducing the problem: I start using a spot light, then when the user clicks on the canvas, I remove the light from the scene and I add a new light (directional). But it doesn't work: there is no lighting, I just see the ambient component. Code is here: http://pastebin.com/BVU0dPi3

Comment: See the Wiki article [How to Update Things with WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates). Also remove all `needsUpdate` flags and add them back in only where they are needed. Avoid `material.color = new THREE.Color()`; use `material.color.copy( color )` instead. `shininess` is not a `THREE.Color`.

Comment: It says "Changes in these require building of new shader program. You'll need to set material.needsUpdate flag to true". So when I move the light I'm setting material.needsUpdate to true, is that all I need to do? It doesn't work (still the same problem).

Comment: You do NOT need to set `material.needsUpdate = true` if you are only _moving_ a light. Set `material.emissive = 0x000000`. Set `material.specular = 0x050505`. Set `material.ambient`to the same value as `material.color`.

Comment: Still nothing to do: if I move the light nothing happens: the shiny area on the cylinder/sphere doesn't move.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? `<input type="number" value="20" id="light-position-z"> </input>`

Comment: I corrected this error. But the problem persists: the spot, directional and area light don't work. If I try to make a similar program where I do not the change the light afterwards, but I set it before starting the scene, and I try to add for example a spot light, it works perfectly. It only doesn't work when I change the light.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you for the help, I've written a new file that is shorter and simpler, to reproduce the problem (see the edit please): when the user clicks it should change the light, but there is no lighting, just the ambient component.

Comment: Sorry, I can answer questions about three.js, but I cannot debug your program for you. I believe you can get it working if you read the wiki article carefully and do what it says to do if you change the number or types of lights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when I was changing the light type, I had to update the material; The same is not valid for when I move the lights. So the program worked by adding this line:

```
// Change type of light and add it to the scene
material.needsUpdate= true;
```